# AngularJS - accordion - assign ng-click and ng-if to element directive directly in directive file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, angular-directive

I am creating an accordion in Angular using custom directives. I have created `<ag-accordion>` directive. This child is `ag-accordion-header` directive as attribute. In html it looks like this:

```
<ag-accordion>
    <div ag-accordion-header>Header 1</div>
    <div>Body 1</div>
    <div ag-accordion-header>Header 2</div>
    <div>Body 2</div>
    <div ag-accordion-header>Header 3</div>
    <div>Body 3</div>
</ag-accordion>
```

My `ag-accordion.directive.js` looks like this:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.widgets')
        .directive('agAccordion', agAccordion)
        .directive('agAccordionHeader', agAccordionHeader);

    function agAccordion () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            controller: controller
        };

        function controller() {

            var vm = this;

            vm.headers = [];

            vm.addHeader = function(header) {
                header.addClass('ag-accordion__header');
                header.next().addClass('ag-accordion__body hidden');
                vm.headers.push(header);
            };

            vm.hidePanels = function() {
                angular.forEach(vm.headers, function (header) {
                    header.next().addClass('hidden');
                });
            };

        }

    }


    function agAccordionHeader() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            require: '^agAccordion',
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            ctrl.addHeader(element);

            element.on('click', function () {
                ctrl.hidePanels();
                element.next().removeClass('hidden');
            });

        }

    }

})();
```

All works fine, but I am using common jQuery "on click" event to fire event (instead ng-click) and I 'hidden' class to show and hide panels (instead ng-if). I want to restructure my directive.js file to using ng-click and ng-if with **no changes in HTML**. So I want to assign angular ng-click and ng-if to all divs using javascript. How can I do it?

Thanks for any help :)

// edit:

Of course, I want to add 'ng' directives to the html code, but using the function in JS instead of manually attributing ng-click and ng-if to each single div.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to change it. `element.on('click', function() {...` in the `link` function is the standard way to do this. If you were to use `ng-if` and `ng-click` instead, it would be on the `<div>` tags but you said you want to do this without changing the HTML. Where else would you place `ng-click` and `ng-if` (if not in the HTML)?

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain it clearly. I want to add this to the html code, but using the function in JS instead of manually attributing ng-click and ng-if to each single div. I understand - I don't need ng-click. But how could I add ng-if to the next element from ag-accordion-header? Something like this: 
`<div ag-accordion-header>Header 1</div><div ng-if="isSelected">Body 1</div>`

Comment: any reason for needing to dynamically add it via js instead of updating the html template. It's the preferred (popular) way in angularjs among developers so there isn't any hidden magic happening when you read the code 1 year+ later.